# How to create --link for 2 containers to link to each other?

Tags: docker

If I have 2 containers, "app_server" and "varnish_server", how can I create --link so that app_server will have a record in the "hosts" file that links to the varnish server, and the varnish_server will have a record in the "hosts" file that links to the app_server?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported by docker directly. You need to have a third party to whom the two containers tell about their existence and can ask for the other:

```
       [service discovery/name service]
            ^                    ^
            |                    |
            v                    v
       [app_server]  <===> [varnish_server]
```

You start the service discovery container first, and link the app_server and varnish_server to that.

Example using etcd on linuxfiddle: http://linuxfiddle.net/f/e124aeeb-2c39-472d-932e-971f092bb6db